# Suppress host attribute rendering in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that has the `title` property.

```
// component code
@Input('title') public title: string

// usage
<dialog [title]="bar"></foo>
```

When the application runs, the rendered markup includes the `title` attribute:

```
<dialog title="bar"></dialog>
```

Is there a way to suppress this? I do need the input attribute, but I don't need it to render in the resulting HTML.

Comment: I don't believe there is such an option. What is the reason you would want to do this, I wonder?

Comment: The `title` attribute renders a tooltip when the element is hovered. Since the `<foo>` element is a container, and may contain other components, it is very undesirable to have a tooltip always visible when the mouse cursor is inside the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering of a given component can be changed by the `Renderer.setElementAttribute` method. Setting an attribute to `null` will remove it from the rendered DOM.

```
constructor (private _elRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'title', null);
}
```

Comment: Very nice find! You can probably make a directive out of this